# Fixed Y axis range AmChart 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I would like my Y axis to go a step from 5 to 5 percent. I've tried everything, this is the closest I got.

```
        var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        valueAxis.title.text = "Patrimônio";
        valueAxis.min = 0;
        valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
        valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
```

This is my code, it works but as the height varies, the range changes. Its data is in percentage, I want to split Y-axis from five to five.

Comment: You have to use [axis ranges](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/custom-valueaxis-grid-using-ranges/).

Comment: I've tried, but it does not fix a step of 5. It changes since my data varies according to input.